# Text-area wrapping not working

Tags: php, html

I have

```
$ad_text=wordwrap(nl2br($_POST['annonsera_text']), 45, '<br />\n');
```

Any idea why the above does display in a long string?

Form `method='POST'`, and `enctype='multipart/form-data'` and `textarea wrap='hard'`.

I want the displayed text-area to look exactly the same as when the user entered the text in it.

**UPDATE:**

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nl
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

OUTPUTS this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Using `wordwrap` function in PHP.

It doesn't seem to make any difference whether I set `wrap="hard"` in HTML either.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a little vague. What happens instead of what you want to happen?

Comment: Show 'before' and 'after' text.  Explain why the 'after' text doesn't match your expectation.

Comment: I have given you all info, I cant figure this out, anything I missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases you should specify fourth parameter of `wordwrap()` function, which instructs it to break words, if they are larger than required width:

```
$ad_text=wordwrap(nl2br($_POST['annonsera_text']), 45, '<br />\n', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this is going to be found in your debugging method. Instead of putting this into one line, separate these out into multiple lines and check the output.

```
echo $ad_text = $_POST['annonsera_text'];
echo $ad_text = nl2br($ad_text);
echo $ad_text = wordwrap($ad_text, 45, '<br />\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

The input string

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nl aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

contains 4 distinct characters: "a", "\n", "l", and " ".

I would expect `nl2br()` to create this output

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br />\nl aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Then the wordwrap call makes this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br<br />\n/>\nl aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

This is ill-formed html.  In the browser, the bad br tags have no effect.  And the newlines don't affect the layout, so it looks like a string of 'a'.  I can't explain where your 'l' goes to.

In your `wordwrap` call, the replacement string is in single quotes, so the '\n' is two characters backslash and n.  Use double quotes to expand the escape into a true newline: Change `'<br />\n'` to `"<br />\n"`

You may also want to leave out the either the `nl2br` call or the `wordwrap` call, depending on what you want.

By the way, have you tried setting the fourth argument, `$cut`, to `true` in the `wordwrap()` call?